# add mutually exclusive data into groups from set of data

Tags: algorithm

I have set of data:

```
offerId  : Variants
  101:     (1)
  102:     (2,3)
  103:     (4)
  104:     (1,2,5)
  105:     (3)
  106:     (4,6)
```

I want to offerIds in separate groups which are mutually exclusive. Like from above data, I'll get two mutually exclusive groups:

```
   [101,102,104,105] corresponding to [(1),(2,3),(1,2,5),(3)]

   [103, 106] corresponding to  [(4),(4,6)]
```

How to I achieve this, pseudocode or logic anything will be appreciated.

P.S  I am writing my code in GO language. But answer in any language will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you need Disjoint-set data structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Comment: Can I get the pseudocode for it?

Answer (score 0):

You need [Disjoint-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) data structure. Another name - Union-find data structure.

You can see pseudocode in Wiki page, and real implementations in numerous sources. [Arbitrary C# example](http://www.mathblog.dk/disjoint-set-data-structure/).

In your case you'll also need  to check intersection of groups (sets?). If intersection  of two groups is not empty, make Union operations for these groups.